# How does string.replace() function work?

Tags: java

This may seem like a odd question, but how does string.replace() work in binary?

Sorry for the short question.

EDIT:

So I guess I didn't make myself clear.

How is the binary for the class variable String searched.  I can't make heads or tails of the source code, so.

Comment: What do you mean _in binary_? Also, the source code is freely available.

Comment: I am home from work now.  This question is MUCH less painful and facepalm-worthy with a beer in-hand.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: If you are working with binary data, you should use a `byte[]`, not a `String`. `String` is composed of two-byte characters, and does not allow certain binary values that are not valid unicode.

Comment: Here is String.java of OpenJDK version 6b14 (not the latest, but I don't think much of it has changed since then): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28char%2Cchar%29

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the replace method works: one is for replacing a "string" with another "string", while the other is for replacing characters in the string with a specified character.

In replacing a "string" sequence with another "string", the Java Virtual Machine will have to load another class (the Matcher class). This other class in turn transforms the target string into something that has no non-terminal regular expression symbols. The transformed String is then searched by the other class for character sequences matching the old character sequence. These character sequences are appended one by one using another class StringBuffer, but this time the replacement is encoded into the buffer memory instead of the "old string" sequence. Control from Matcher class will then return to the String class. I won't elaborate on this part that much since we're talking about another class here.

In replacing characters in the string with a specified character, control of the Java Virtual Machine remains within the "binary" instructions of the String class. First, it is checked whether there is actually a replacement that will happen. Things such as equality of the new and old characters, and existence of the target character, are checked. Once these "tests" are passed, a sequence of Unicode characters is created as a copy of the target String's value. This sequence of characters is traversed, and then the location of each "old" character is filled up one by one with the bit sequence of the "new" character. Once the actual filling up completes, a new class of type String is created out of the said sequence of characters. The resulting String is returned.

Of course, this answer could be expounded even more. I hope peeps can help me with my questions too.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. "transforms the target string into something that has no regular expression"? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @user2357112 What I meant was no non-terminal regular expression symbols. I edited the answer already. Thanks, I didn't notice that my answer for the 1st replace stopped there.

Comment: `replace` doesn't use regexes, though. It replaces literal character sequences.

Comment: Yeah, replace doesn't use regexes. So when you input a "(" for example, that should be replaced. A call to Matcher inside String processes these symbols.

Comment: Oh, it delegates to the regex engine with the LITERAL flag rather than having its own specialized replacement code. I didn't know about that flag before.

Comment: Yes. String delegates to the regex engine. :)